# Can you make the game save regional match making setting?

Tags: dota-2

Before you start your queue you can set up matchmaking settings. There you have *Game Modes*, *Region* and *Language* options.

Now I have set them all up to my liking, but I have a problem with regional setting. The game seems to save/remember all other settings I've selected except in which regions do I want to play. So every time I start the game, I have to pick regions all over again.

Is this some kind of bug, or is the game made that way? Is there a way to make the game remember my region settings too?

Comment: Mine saves, dunno.

Comment: it's a bug. it's not supposed to be like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug that was affecting some players (including me). It has been fixed with minipatch on May 1st, 2013.

Patch notes:

> UI
>   - Fixed an issue where matchmaking region selections were not being saved correctly. These selections have been reset and players will have to re-select their regions.